# Apache Kafka does not consume from api

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The console commands of kafka-console-producer.sh and kafka-console-consumer.sh are functioning properly but when I try to produce or consume using the api, I am not able to! Can someone tell me if there is something wrong with my scala code?

```
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord}

object ScalaProducerExample  {
  val topic = "test"
  val brokers = "<broker>:9092"
  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", brokers)
  props.put("client.id", "ScalaProducerExample")
  props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
  val data = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "message")
  producer.send(data)
  producer.close()
}
```

This is the dependencies loaded in build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.8.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.2.0"
```

I even wrote it in Java and the same is happening.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientRequest;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.KafkaClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.RequestCompletionHandler;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Node;
import org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractRequest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProducerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String topic = "test";
        String brokers = "<broker>:9092";
        System.out.println("init " );
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);


        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        System.out.println("creating prducer " );
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
        producer.flush();
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, "1", "2"));
        producer.close();
        System.out.println("close  " );
    }
}
```

The dependencies in built.sbt are:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.8.2.1"
```

I know that the connection works because, when I change the broker, I receive an error. But when the broker is correct, the program runs successfully, but I am not receiving any message.

**Update:** I am assuming that the reason the program runs successfully is that it gives timeout. 
I ran this

```
try {
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, "1", "2")).get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And got this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after waiting for 30000 ms.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:64)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:25)
        at de.innocow.kafka.ProducerExample.main(ProducerExample.java:45)
```

How can I debug more than this and investigate why the producer is not sending?

Comment: Are you really running that old version of Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, "1", "2"));
producer.flush();            
producer.close();
```

Try with this and see the [Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#flush()) :

> ```
> The flush() call gives a convenient way to ensure all previously sent messages have actually completed. 
>  This example shows how to consume from one Kafka topic and produce to another Kafka topic:
> ```

```
 for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record: consumer.poll(100))
     producer.send(new ProducerRecord("my-topic", record.key(), record.value());
 producer.flush();
 consumer.commit();
```

Comment: I tested flushing but it is not working. And I was not expecting it to work actually, because I am just having everything new, so there is no previous message for me to 'ensure all previously sent messages have actually completed.'. The problem is that it gets stuck at sending and after timeout it closes. I have updated the issue. Can you take a look at the update section and suggest me a solution if you have any.